# No provider for Http Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('name') @Optional() public name?: string) {            
}
```

inside appModule I'm trying to use provider for my service

```
MyService,
imports: [ // import Angular's modules
HttpModule,    
....,
    [
      { provide: 'username', useValue: 'default' }         
    ],

const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
      [MyService,
        {
          provide: 'name', useValue: 'abc'
        }
      ]);
```

But I'm getting

> ERROR Error: No provider for Http! (MyService -> Http)

Comment: Yes, I am register HttpModule inside @NgModule({ imports:[ HttpModule], ...

Comment: which is your angular version?

Comment: @SurajRao It's Angular2

Comment: @Igor, I'm using Http without problems when my service constructor not expecting injecting.

Comment: It could be a typo maybe? import { Http } from '@angular/http'; Note it's lower case http for the filename.

Comment: impplements on Init in a service?

Comment: Do you import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';  in your app.module ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi yeah, good eye. Left there mistakenly, after removing OnInit same errors applies.

Comment: @JorgeMejia yes I do import HttpModule, already answer that.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts import both:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Then add them to your imports:

```
imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
```

Remember to add your service to the providers:

```
providers: [
    ...
    MyService
    ...

  ],
```

Then add the following to your service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

the add it to your constructor referring to HttpClient instead of Http, like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you do realize that I'm using angular 2? I don't have access to '@angular/common/http'