# Error: No provider for Http! (MyService -> Http)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 2.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('name') @Optional() public name?: string) {            
}
```

inside appModule I'm trying to use provider for my service

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http/';



 @NgModule({
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [
    App    
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules    
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
 ],
  providers: [    
    Http, // if I comment this out I'm getting ERROR Error: No provider for 
          // Http! (MyService -> Http)
    MyService, 
    [
      {  provide: 'name', useValue: ''  }      
    ],
....,
```

Inside AppComponent I'm using Reflective injector

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
      [MyService,
        {
          provide: 'name', useValue: 'my name'
        }
      ]);
```

But I'm getting 
case one:
Inside providers if I have following

```
providers: [ Http ]
```

then I'm getting

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ConnectionBackend! ;
>   Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for
>   ConnectionBackend!

and if left Http out, `providers: [ ]` I'm getting

> Error: No provider for Http! (MyService -> Http)

On actual service I'm having constructor like

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('name') @Optional() public name?: string) {

    }
```

**Update:**
inside AppComponent I'm injecting 
constructor(private parentInjector:Injector){
}

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
      [MyService,
        {
          provide: 'name', 'abc'
        }
      ], this.parentInjector);

    this.security = injector.get(MyService);
```

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ConnectionBackend! ;
>   Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for
>   ConnectionBackend!

Comment: Plunkr please...

Comment: Why are you creating an injector in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? And why do you use a string as token instead of using the recommended InjectionToken?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322345/no-provider-for-http-angular-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for Http Angular service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322345/no-provider-for-http-angular-service)

Comment: @JBNizet  
I follow this example stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubo2ok?file=app%2Fapp.component.‌​ts where I want to extend this and use http inside Car for consuming web service.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why don't you just inject HttpCLient into Car, and inject Car into your component. Why do you create an Injector?

Comment: I don't know for injector itself (just followed an example) I basically want to inject string name from AppComponent to the Car which will append name to the url in order to be consumed.

Comment: If the name is different for every component calling the Car service, then pass the name as an argument to the service methods. Don't inject the name into the service.

Answer (score 0):

Use this module for latest version of Angular:

`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: He's not using the latest version of Angular, he's using Angular2

Comment: Doesn't matter, its just a module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parent injector (from the Angular application), otherwise the created injector will only know the providers you pass explicitely

```
constructor(private parentInjector:Injector) {

}
 ...

 const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
  [MyService,
    {
      provide: 'name', useValue: 'my name'
    }
  ], this.parentInjector);
```

See also https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector#resolveAndCreate

Comment: Can you please check my update, I tried with parentInjector but still problem occures.

Comment: You still haven't answered the comment below your question why you think you need to create an injector at all.

Comment: I think you need to create a reproduction on http://stackblitz.com It's too difficult to figure out what you're doing from the fragments.

Comment: I follow this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubo2ok?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts where I want to use http inside Car for consuming web service.