# How to resolve HTTP dependency in angular 5 using ReflectiveInjector

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I want to resolve Http using ReflectiveInjector and not via injecting in constructor.

Below is my code

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


private http;

constructor()
{
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        (<any>HttpClientModule).decorators[0].args[0].providers
    ]);
    this.http = injector.get(HttpClient);
    console.log(this.http)
}
```

It works fine when i use ng serve, but when I build the project it throws error, Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

**Note :** I am working on Angular 5 project.

Comment: if youre using angular 5, you should be using the `HttpClientModule`, not the deprecated `HttpModule`

Comment: Seems weird. What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you creating a new injector, why are you not just passing the parent injector instead of accessing the providers of the module in such a weird way. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336439/217408

Comment: You have XY problem. Please, explain instead what task you're trying to solve.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon (<any>HttpClientModule).decorators is not available in build but works on localhost:4200, do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: no because i use the constructor to inject it

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I want to create an object of HttpClient, so i want to avoid dependency injection and use ReflectiveInjector

Comment: @mast3rd3mon that is what I want to avoid. :)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: why? doing it yourself is just reinventing the wheel

Comment: I am creating a service which will call this http service and more services together.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a valid reason and also not like a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to to list all providers in your injector like they are in **`HttpModule`**:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
    {provide: Http, useFactory: httpFactory, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]},
    BrowserXhr,
    {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
    {provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions},
    XHRBackend,
    {provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: _createDefaultCookieXSRFStrategy},
  ])
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/http_module.ts#L46-L55

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8h71fs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

The providers for the **`HttpClientModule`** can be found in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/common/http/src/module.ts#L119-L132

Comment: cannot find name httpFactory and _createDefaultCookieXSRFStrategy ? how to deal with it ?

Comment: Just replacing it by `useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy()` should do it

Comment: useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy() worked but other error is there, cannot find name httpFactory. what to do ?

Comment: also  injector.get(HttpClient) and  injector.get(Http) throws error. No provider for Http!